# Recoger valor de un datepicker en Angular 5

Tags: angular, datepicker

Tengo el siguiente datepicker

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Hoy">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

y necesito recoger el valor de la fecha para poder almacenarlo posteriormente en una `base de datos`.

Comment: con la etiqueta `formControlName="nombre_var"`

Comment: Si no añades el código del controlador, no vamos a poder ayudarte. Quizá deberías primero ver como funcionan los form (formularios) en Angular, especialmente los *reactivos*